# Tracking a rogue jQuery through the wilderness

Tags: jquery

I have a legacy app that gets loaded by multiple other apps (with more on the way). I recently tracked down and temporarily eliminated a problem with two competing jQuery instances (one slim, one not slim). However, in doing so, I discovered that there's a *third* version of jquery getting loaded from... somewhere. I've looked through the codebase but can't find it, I only know a few key points that its executing at.

Is there a way I can have jquery output to console the location of the file that it's running from? I've searched the documentation, but so far I have only found commands to output version, not its source location.

Comment: use the network tab on your browser to identify its source

Comment: I've tried that. I'm only seeing the jQuery I actually want, not the jQuery I need to find. I suspect it's included in some kind of bundle, but there's a lot of them, and all minified.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out you can do this with a single pure javascript command:

```
$(function(){ 
   //Inside jQuery that's placed when the rogue jquery is expected to be loaded
   // Place console trace. The $ namespace will fire from the file
   // that is currently loaded by. 
    console.trace();
   // Console trace will output a list of files and locations involved with the call, which makes figuring out the origin file of a jQuery instance usually fairly easy.
});
```

which shows the files used in an active call. Including that in a jquery call is able to output to the console all the files made during the call, which catches the current rogue jQuery. Just drop it in the middle of the functions you're trying to figure out what file they're calling.